# Jquery Multiselect plugin using in asp.net listbox and events

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select

I want to use http://loudev.com/ this plugin for listboxes which comes with theme.
html codes

```
                            <div class="span2">

                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label"></label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="listboxAdd" SelectionMode="Multiple" Rows="10" />
                                        <span class="help-inline text-center">Group List</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="span1">
                                <br />
                                &nbsp;<br />
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label"></label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnRemove" CssClass="btn red block" OnClick="btnRemove_Click">&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="m-icon-swapleft m-icon-white"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;</asp:LinkButton>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br />
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label"></label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnAdd" CssClass="btn green block" OnClick="btnAdd_Click">&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;</asp:LinkButton>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="span2">

                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label"></label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="listboxAdded" SelectionMode="Multiple" Rows="10" />
                                        <span class="help-inline text-center">Added Groups</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
```

c# code

```
//for group list
    private void Group_Load()
    {
        listboxAdd.Items.Clear();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = myTracking.Master_Group_Load(Int32.Parse(Company.Value)).Tables[0];

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            listboxAdd.DataTextField = "Group_Name";
            listboxAdd.DataValueField = "Group_ID";
            listboxAdd.DataSource = dt;
            listboxAdd.DataBind();

        }
    }

      //for added group

    private void Added_Group_Load()
    {
        listboxAdded.Items.Clear();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable(); ;
        dt = myTracking.Object_Group_Load(Int32.Parse(hd_objectID.Value)).Tables[0];

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            listboxAdded.DataTextField = "Group_Name";
            listboxAdded.DataValueField = "Object_Group_ID";
            listboxAdded.DataSource = dt;
            listboxAdded.DataBind();

        }
    }



     // add to right side (insert table) [added group]
    private void Group_Insert()
    {

        try
        {
            myTracking.Object_Group_Insert(Int32.Parse(listboxAdd.SelectedValue), Int32.Parse(hd_objectID.Value), Session["IPADDRESS"].ToString(), Session["GetMACAddress"].ToString(), Int32.Parse(Company.Value), Int32.Parse(Session["Child_Company_ID"].ToString()));
            Added_Group_Load();
            Call_Alert("alert-success");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            Call_Alert("alert-error");
        }

    }


     //remove from right side [added group]
    private void Group_Remove()
    {
        try
        {
            myTracking.Object_Group_Delete(Int32.Parse(listboxAdded.SelectedValue));
            Added_Group_Load();
            Call_Alert("alert-success", "<i class=" + "icon-ok" + "></i> <strong> Gruptan Çıkarıldı!..</strong>");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Call_Alert("");
        }
    }

    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int groupId, objectID;
        if (TryParsing(listboxAdd.SelectedValue, out groupId) && TryParsing(listboxAdd.SelectedValue, out objectID))
        {
            Group_Insert();
        }
        else
        {
            Call_Alert("");
        }
    }

    protected void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int ObjectID;
        if (TryParsing(listboxAdded.SelectedValue, out ObjectID))
        {
            Group_Remove();
        }
        else
        {
            Call_Alert("");
        }
    }
```

This works fine for asp.net elemwnts and logic but I want to adapt it jquery multiselect.js

```
var handleMultiSelect = function () {
        $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_listboxAdd').multiSelect();
        }
```

If use this it hides first one [group list] and create two listbox first one has group list and second one is empty.  If I click an item its added second one by js.

I want it full works iwth this plugin if I click first one it triggers `Group_Insert()` and when I click it called `Group_remove()` like buttons click event. how is it possible?

Comment: UP!
   
  
`Any idea?`

Comment: @sangram parmar anybody think to help me?